# Can I include a CSS StyleSheet from a local drive, in a page served from a web site

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a page, served by a web site, containing a  to a stylesheet, that is available not on the web site, and not on a different web site, but on a local drive.

Something like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="/styles/something.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="file:///C:/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
```

My initial research shows that browsers don't seem to support this, but I'm willing to be proved wrong, or discover some sneaky way of doing it. (I tried the above, that doesn't work.)

[I know, I know, you wanna know "why". This is for the site designer - it would allow him to edit the css locally while designing and see the effect on the "semi-live" site. ie the round-trip for edits would be very fast, and I wouldn't need to give him access to the actual site. By extension, for teaching purposes, it would allow multiple people to simultaneously practice their CSS skills locally]

Obviously any edits made to the local file will only be visible on that local computer - that's the whole idea. If you had 10 students each would see the same site with a different css file.

Comment: You can, if there's one computer in the world, assuming its a PC. :P

Comment: if you can setup a local server for all the machines that will be accessing your test site, you can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you can setup Apache on your machine, this is easily done.

This is assuming the question is this

> I want to be able to have a site in a
>   central location (live) and allow users
>   accessing that site to be able to make
>   changes to the site by editing a local
>   file. These changes will *only* be
>   visible to the person making the
>   change and the rest will just see
>   whatever CSS is on their local copy.

So this means that you have to serve a local file from multiple computers and each person viewing the site may have a different looking copy. If I'm right, read on.

Setup a local environment (maybe with WAMP?) on all the machines you want to be able to allow local edits. The important thing is that everyone must have the same hostname defined (either localhost, or something else - don't forget to add it to your `hosts` file). Place the CSS file inside your webroot and add a link to your live site pointing to that link.

```
<link href="http://www.mysite.com/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://localhost/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And voila! Local editing.

**Caveats**

1. Everyone needs to have their files placed in the same local URL otherwise it won't work
2. You need to setup a local environment (very easy)

Answer (score 7):

Just press Shift+F7 on Firefox (or Tools->Web Developer->Style Editor). In the window that opens you can import an entire file or you can also edit the styles loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, you can't. But why not try it and find out if this didn't work?

If the purpose of your needs is only for testing, i'll advice you install [web developer extension](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) where you can add local CSS to a website - for testing only.

Comment: Thanks Fabrik - yeah I did try it, and yeah it doesn't work. I've edited the post to make that clear. I was just asking in case someone knew of a good hack to achieve this effect.

Comment: As i said, you can install web developer toolbar but this will *only visible for you*.

Comment: yeah, I'm checking into that now. The "C drive" file is only visible to the person making the edits, so that's the same restriction. (That's a restriction I want anyway).

Comment: @S.M.09 - can you elaborate. I don't have an "inline" Css on the page. I was linking to other .css files though - I've tried removing those and it still doesn't seem to read the c:\custom file. Am I missing something?

Comment: Alternatively you can run a script and change the 'href' of the link tag by taking the input from user... Something like this `document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0].href='user_entered_css_url'` Note: The css should be running on a machine's url one gives.... That to is not permanent though..

Comment: @Bruce - In the CSS menu navigate to Disable Style and check the box next to Linked Style Sheets...this will disable any of the CSS files linked and removing the CSS inline is optional depending on whether your page has inline CSS...

Comment: "Obviously" you can't? file:/// URLs work fine for images, why not CSS then?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the purpose of answering the question, yes he could serve a CSS file to your website, but he would have to have a server installed on his computer and a public access to his server IP.

Then in the `href` of the stylesheet you would write something like `<link href="190.181.169.118/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`.

Of course this is not the recommended solution, i would advise you to use some sort of browser extension / plug in for that.

Comment: I've been considering this approach. It's trivial to build a tiny exe, bound to 127.0.0.1 port whatever, running on the local machine, which serves pretty much just 1 file. Then the site can include a <link> to the "local file" as you describe. 

I've looked at a bunch of plugins so far but they don't seem to "remember" between page refreshes, and they don't seem to apply "site wide" - at least not that I've found.

Comment: @bruce you could point it to localhost and just have apache running in your local machine.

Comment: @JohnP - yes, I'm thinking this is the right approach in the long run. I wouldn't need anything quite as fancy as apache - any really tiny web server will do (and as it happens I have one of those). But it seems to be the "cleanest" solution from the designers point of view. By running it on a wacky port (not 80) it'll also not interfere with other programs.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can!! Just need **Firefox** as a browser and you also need add on **WEB DEVELOPER** installed on it...

It allows to disable the inline CSS and add user CSS...

Download the add on [WEBDEVELOPER](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

Once installed...after you restart firefox you will get a menu on the firefox window in which click on the **CSS** menu which will allow you options to disable and add user CSS

You will have to disable the inline CSS to see the CSS applied by the user to full effect

Comment: I've been trying this for a few minutes now, but there seem to be a couple problems.
a) it applies "per page" not "per site" and
b) it forgets the setting if I refresh the page.
am I missing some settings?

Comment: That is how its desingned to work it only applies to a single page... every time you refresh the page is loaded from the server with the original inline CSS...You cannot make it permanent for the page every time you load it...you will have to change it every time the page reloads....

Comment: @Bruce Web Developer has a setting to "Persist Features."  For me, it's the last button on the right (the little light switch).  It's the first option.  This only works on one visit (e.g., if you close the browser, it will revert to the default).

Comment: @Rockerest, yeah I found that, and then it pops open a filedialog (at least on my machine) on every page refresh, so the css file can be reselected. It's close, but not exactly user friendly...

Comment: Is there another plug in or developer tools that mean you dont have to specify the file on every single page reload?