# How to set path to enable and integrate bootstrap css,js and font files/class into html when html file and bootstrap files are at different location

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Demmo</title>
   <link  href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container">
    <form role="form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text"  class="form-control" name="">
   </div>
   </form>
   </div>


</body>
</html>
```

My HTML file is at this location-->  C:\wamp\www\Ajax_Database\demo.html and
My Bootstrap's css,js,fonts classes/files  are at this location--> D:\Bootstrap\bootstrap-3.3.7\dist

then how can add bootstrap into my html to use bootstrap's feature.....

Answer (score 2):

You cannot include css/js/etc files from your local drives (unless your intention is that every single user has a copy of bootstrap.min.css in their own D drive). See here for explanation: [Including files from local drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495907/can-i-include-a-css-stylesheet-from-a-local-drive-in-a-page-served-from-a-web-s)

There are two ways to include CSS files in your website:

1. Create a folder called: *Content* in the root of your website, Add your bootstrap.min.css in this folder. Now reference this file like this:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
   ```
2. If you don't want to download and host Bootstrap yourself, you can include it from a CDN (Content Delivery Network), like this:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   ```

[See here for more info about CDN](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp)